# How to open output in gnome terminal insteed of console in eclipse CDT

Tags: command-line, eclipse

I am currently working on eclipse CDT in Ubuntu 16.04. When I run a program it displays output in console tab but I want it to display it in gnome terminal. How to do it?

Comment: Possible match: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098894/how-to-use-terminal-view-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You just have to insert the `gnome-terminal` application location (`/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`), specify the working directory of the project "slash" the folder where the executable will be (In my case, Debug). The use of variables makes it work for other projects.

Finally, you have to tell the terminal to execute the file in the arguments.

[image: screenshot of External Tools Configuration dialog]